# How to loop through groups with now.js

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

is there a way to loop through a user's groups with now.js?

When a user disconnects, I want to run some functions on the groups that they were a part of.

something like answer 1 here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947391/nowjs-group-leave-event-called-multiple-times)), but for some reason, that code doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
nowjs.on('disconnect', function() { 
    var that = this;
    this.getGroups(function(groups){
         for (i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
             nowjs.getGroup(groups[i]).removeUser(that.user.clientId);
             console.log('user removed');
         }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you add your code and specifics on "doesn't work"?

Comment: It appears that support for the now.js module has ended, despite how useful it is: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nowjs/FZXWZr22vn8

Comment: ya...I figured that out :( That stinks! Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I had already created an array called serverRoomsList. That held, oddly enough, a list of all the chat rooms I had already created. I just looped through that to get all of the group names.

However, I would still like to know if Now itself keeps track of groups in an array, or if I have to do it.